# Websphere 6.1 and BASIC Authentication

Tags: authentication, websphere, websphere-6.1

I have a sample file for BASIC page authentication that works perfectly in tomcat but it wont work at all in websphere. Any ideas what needs to be done differently in Websphere?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Code sample, stack trace / log please...

Comment: Are you able to "install new application" in websphere with the generated war file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Damien,

Please review Chapter 7 of the Websphere 6.1 Security Handbook titled "Securing a Web application":
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246316.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled global security on Websphere?